# How to parse CSV with values that contain a comma?

Tags: php, csv

Assuming you have a string as follows:

```
$str = 'one value, two value, "three, cool value", four value';
```

How would you make it an array as follows:

```
$arr = array('one value', 'two value', 'three, cool value', 'four value');
```

(That's all about CSV and values that contain a comma and thus are double quoted.)

Answer (score 9):

If you are really parsing it from a string, use [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

If you are reading data from a file, use [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv).

Comment: Note that if you're using PHP < 5.3, and you need to read it from a string, you can use the 'var' stream wrapper. See http://codepad.org/XepyeDSd

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
$str = 'one value, two value, "three, cool value", four value';
var_dump(str_getcsv($str));
```

Results:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "one value"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "two value"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "three, cool value"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "four value"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using 5.3.0 or newer, use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv). If you're using an older version of PHP, try [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) with the 'var' stream wrapper from [here](http://php.net/stream.streamwrapper.example-1). An example of the last can be found at [this codepad](http://codepad.org/XepyeDSd).

Answer (score 1):

[str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) use this function with enclosure as `'\"'`.

It looks like this: `$csv = str_getcsv($csvstring,',','\"');`

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_getcsv` together with `array_map` and `trim` does precisely this. You use `str_getcsv` to break the items into an array, and then `array_map` and `trim` to trim off the whitespace from each item.

## PHP → JSON Format

#### WITHOUT TRIM

```php
echo json_encode(str_getcsv('one value, two value, "three, cool value", four value'));
```

This produces:

```json
// some array items include extra whitespace without `trim()`
["one value"," two value","three, cool value"," four value"]
```

#### WITH TRIM

```php
echo json_encode(array_map('trim', str_getcsv('one value, two value, "three, cool value", four value')));
```

This produces:

```json
["one value","two value","three, cool value","four value"]
```

## PHP Format

To use the final result in JSON format, use `echo json_encode(…)` as I did above. Otherwise, if you would like to continue using this as a PHP array, then use `var_dump(…)` without json_encode. You can do it like here (including `trim()`):

```php
var_dump(array_map('trim', str_getcsv('one value, two value, "three, cool value", four value')));
```

This produces:

```php
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "one value"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "two value"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "three, cool value"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "four value"
}
```

This is correct PHP format, the PHP equivalent of:

```json
["one value","two value","three, cool value","four value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look around at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways.

1. If you're going to quote entries, quote every entries. Then explode the string with "," (with quotes).
2. Replace commas with something uncommon before parsing. Like {|}

Comment: No need to do that, actually - both fgetcsv() and str_getcsv() handle the quoting style demonstrated just fine.